# How to Start Scenebuilder with Java 11

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, javafx-11

on the way towards Java 11 I'm checking my toolkit, 
among it the SceneBuilder.

I'm using java-11 in combination with javafx-sdk-11 and
started the SceneBuilder with

/opt/jdk-11/bin/java --module-path javafx-sdk-11/lib  --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar

The UI looks ok, but any attempt to create a scene gives some errors:

```
    (java:10329): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2451: signal 'expose-event' is invalid for instance '0x7f395831e720' of type 'GtkWindow'
    Sep. 05, 2018 10:26:17 NACHM. com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$SceneBuilderUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
    SEVERE: An exception was thrown:

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make void javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.setStaticLoad(boolean) accessible: module javafx.fxml does not "opens javafx.fxml" to unnamed module @42efe4f4
```

What would be the best way to use the Scenebuilder with Java 11 ?

Thanks, Carsten

Comment: Try adding `--add-opens javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED` to the command line. The issue is that Scene Builder is trying to reflective access `FXMLLoader` but the module `javafx.fxml` doesn't permit this (because it doesn't `opens` the package to the unnamed module). This would have resulted in a warning in Java 9 or 10 but it's possible Java 11 now denies access by default. Another option might be to use `--illegal-access=permit` but this option is marked to be removed in a future release.

Comment: You may want to file a bug report if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: Hello Slaw, I tried it but now get some deep down exception when trying drag and drop:
(java:5768): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2451: signal 'expose-event' is invalid for instance '0x7efd843c2720' of type 'GtkWindow'

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get that warning on Windows. And as far as I can tell this is a problem with native code.

Comment: I can run it on Mac as well, no warnings. It looks like is a Linux issue with Gtk. Can you try it with Gtk 2 using `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`?

Comment: @CarstenZerbst related to the drag and drop issue with Gtk3 there is a JDK issue closed in June 2019 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211302

Answer (score 0):

I have looked high and low for an answer - to the problem of running SceneBuilder on Linux on a HiDPI configuration - and this thread seemed innocuous and irrelevant to the HiDPI issue at first - but it provided the answer over a few responses - I will summarise if I may:

To put it all together; for Ubuntu 20 on GTK

```
cd /opt/SceneBuilder
java --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib \
  --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing \
  --add-opens javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dglass.gtk.uiScale=2.0 -Djdk.gtk.version=2 \
  -jar app/scenebuilder-11.0.0-all.jar
```

I also had to

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

To get rid of a related error warning in starting up SceneBuilder.

Change the following paths according to your install:

- Note the install location of the JavaFX SDK (as specified in --module-path)
- Note the location of SceneBuilder
- Note the uiScale scaling factor.  Tweak this to make SceneBuilder workable.
- By not adding gtk.version; resulted in a working UI; but very funky errors on mouse drag and drop.

Big thanks to all the contributors - the HiDPI issue was really troubling me while other threads all pointing to it being fixed and "just working".  Hope this helps somebody.